# Getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message Error While Storing the data into database [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel

Hi am new in laravel and am trying to store the data into database and get this error:

**MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message**

here i created the resources

```
Routes:
Route::resource("/post","PostController");
```

Here is the store method in my PostController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{


    Post::create($request->all());
    return redirect('post');

}
```

Here is my HTML form for post

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Create Post</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
    {{  csrf_field() }}

    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter Title"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Post Model

```
<?php

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Post extends Model
 {
 protected $fillable = ["_token","title"];
 protected $table = 'Post';
  }
```

here is my route list:

[Route List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgCF2.png)

Here is full error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9TtD.png)

Comment: Add an action to your form `<form action="post" method="post">`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a form action here, post.store should work considering that you are using a resource controller':

```
<form action="{{ route('post.store') }}" method="post">
```

If this doesn't help let me know.

Comment: Sorry edited to post.store after viewing your routes list

Comment: fantastic - you did great posting everything nice and clearly - please mark answer as correct if you are happy with everything :) @HimanshuRahi

Answer (score 0):

Specify the action in the form.

You can update the HTML to this and it should work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Create Post</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="{{ url('/post') }}" method="post">
    {{  csrf_field() }}

    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter Title"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is because the create route is `/post/create` and the store route is `/post`. Because no action is specified, the form will post to `/post/create` instead which is why the exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the data to the view.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = Post::create($request->all());
    return redirect('post')->with('data',$data);
}
```

with the following route->

```
Route::post('/post', 'PostController@store');
```